# VBA - copy and paste between sheets not pasting in the right location

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to paste some data from one sheet to another.

The first button press works as it is designed to (updating a row i45 etc).

The second button press was meant to paste data to the next row (i46 etc..) as it is empty row) but it actually updates the row i21 any subsequent presses just update i21 overwriting.

Can you please check what I have done wrong.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Raw")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Week Data (all)")

copySheet.Range("H15:AA15").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(45, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because with `pasteSheet.Cells(45, 9)` you are always starting your search at Row 45.  Instead, you should start your search at `.Rows.Count`, which is the absolutely last row in your column (ie. 1048576).  Therefore, try...

```
With pasteSheet
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

Comment: ++ I love it when I see a code where objects are fully qualified :) You may want to also mention what OP was doing wrong...

Comment: @Siddharth I've just added an explanation.  Thanks for the advice.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for helping, I get the following error   "pastespecial method of range class failed" on the  .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues line of code

Comment: Did you include that line within the **With/EndWith** statements?

Comment: I see, thanks again. I only have one issue. I have a total at the bottom of the worksheet and all the data is posting below that. is there a way to have the data paste at 45, 9 and work down from there or can I only have it work up from the bottom until it finds a populated cell? Or can I have it ignore the cells with the total in when it looks for populated cells?

Comment: We can start search from the first row in Column I, that is I1, until we find the last used row.  And then we can add 1 to that number to get the next row.  However, what if the last used row is the row containing the total?  Do you want to insert a new row?

Comment: Thanks bro, its ok I will change the way the sheet is laid out. Your solution has given me a few ideas to work with.

Answer (score 0):

also this mothod same.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim vDB
Dim rngT As Range
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Raw")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Week Data (all)")

    vDB = copySheet.Range("H15:AA15")

    Set rngT = pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp)(2)
    rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```